# Tiling PDF with SubsamplingScaleImageView (davemorrissey lib)

Tags: android

Is it possible to use pdf files with SubsamplingScaleImageView, Dave Morrissey lib ?

Txs for help

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, as `SubsamplingScaleImageView` does not support PDF.

On Android 5.0+, you can use `PdfRenderer` to generate bitmaps from PDF pages, and use those with `SubsamplingScaleImageView`. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/PDF/PdfRenderer) demonstrates this. However, `PdfRenderer` not only requires Android 5.0, but it cannot handle complex PDFs. I recommend using something else — [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html) outlines some options.

Comment: Txs for your response, but I was searching for a way to manipulate pdf (big pdf, really big...)

Comment: @Hiromi: If by "really big" you are referring to page size, convert it to a bitmap elsewhere (your server, your development machine for packaged content) using better tools for converting PDFs to bitmaps. Or, [use `AndroidPdfViewer`](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/) with a suitable value in `setMaxZoom()`.